# sublime text 3 command mapped to key binding

Tags: sublimetext3, evernote

So I am using sublime text 3 and the evernote plugin for it, which is awesome.  However, I don't want to keep having to go to command and in inputting a new

```
{ "keys": ["YOUR_SEQUENCE"], "command": "YOUR_COMMAND" }
```

So applying this, I tried to run this in the console:

```
>>> { "keys": ["leftshift+leftsuper+u"], "command": "Evernote: Update Evernote Note" }
{'keys': ['leftshift+leftsuper+u'], 'command': 'Evernote: Update Evernote Note'}
```

Which seemed to work.  However, when I go to do `Shift` and `Command` and `u` nothing happens, did I do something wrong?

Comment: Pasting the code into the console won't work. You have to [add it to the key bindings file](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html), which you can get to via the main menu -> preferences -> key bindings -user.

Answer (score 1):

As commenter stated, you need to put this in sublime keymapping file.  Your file should look like this:

```
[
   { "keys": ["leftshift+leftsuper+u"], "command": "save_evernote_note" }
]
```